# Using JavaScript .join() results in misaligned vertical characters

Tags: javascript, alignment, vertical-alignment, text-alignment

I'm using the following code to wrap every word inside two span elements:

```html
<p data-anim="wrap-words">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
```

```js
function wrapWords() {
    const strings = document.querySelectorAll('[data-anim="wrap-words"]');
    
    for (let i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
        const string = strings[i];
        const words = string.textContent.split(' ');
        const wrappedWords = words.map(word => `<span><span>${word}</span></span>`);
        const wrappedString = wrappedWords.join(' ');
        
        string.innerHTML = wrappedString;
    }
} wrapWords();
```

I split by spaces and re-add these spaces again in the join statement. This causes the spaces to be misaligned vertically, which screws with the visual line-height.

Instead of joining with a `' '` I joined with an `'x'` to visualize the problem better: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZZkM.png)

Does anybody have an idea why this happens? I couldn't find anything about this error. CSS `vertical-align` does not seem to influence anything.

```js
function wrapWords() {
    const strings = document.querySelectorAll('[data-anim="wrap-words"]');

    strings.forEach(string => {
        const words = string.textContent.split(' ');
        const wrappedWords = words.map(word => `<span><span>${word}</span></span>`);
        const wrappedString = wrappedWords.join('x');

        string.innerHTML = wrappedString;
    });
} wrapWords();
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.375;
    color: #000;
    font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    padding: 2vw;
}

/* paragraph */
.paragraph p {
    max-width: 20rem;
}

/* anim */
[data-anim="wrap-words"] > span {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}
[data-anim="wrap-words"] span span {
    display: inline-block;
    animation-name: slideFromBottom;
    animation-duration: .75s;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.2,0,.2,1);
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@keyframes slideFromBottom {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(100%);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container paragraph">
    <p data-anim="wrap-words" data-delayDelta=".0025">In ac sagittis nibh. Duis eleifend tortor ac nunc pretium, sit amet sollicitudin lectus pretium. Nulla laoreet ac tellus id imperdiet. Sed molestie iaculis varius. Fusce commodo lacinia dapibus. Pellentesque ullamcorper lectus at erat volutpat cursus.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Confusing that you call a variable `strings` when it is not an array of strings.

Comment: The problem you describe depends on some CSS you have. Please edit your question and insert a Stack Snippet using the toolbar menu, and provide HTML, CSS and JS so we can run the code and see the effect.

Comment: @trincot I added a snippet. Variable naming sucks, that's true. But neither that nor the CSS i wrote has anything to do with the problem, I think.

Comment: It is easy to see it *is* related to your CSS: if you remove all CSS the problem is gone. Drilling down, the problem is resolved if you remove `display: inline-block;` from `[data-anim="wrap-words"] > span`

Comment: `display: inline-block` was needed for some further styling regarding animations, since `display: inline` does not always work with `overflow: hidden`. But I was able to change it from `inline-block` to `inline-flex` and now everything works. Thanks @trincot!